# ssl certificate self signed instead of valid

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate-authority

I've purchased a valid certificate:

For example this site validates it:
https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/?url=www.example.com

But when I test it with openSSL, like this:

> openssl s_client -showcerts -connect
>   https://www.example.com:443

I get

> Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)

Answer (score 12):

## SNI-Hole

You've fallen into a [SNI hole](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/91717/78662).

SNI is [server name indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). This allows you have multiple different hostnames living on the same shared IP. And if you don't actually indicate a servername to a SNI enabled server, then you get back the default certificate. (This is the "SNI hole" part.)

And OpenSSL will not supply a servername to the TLS server unless you tell it to. Use the `-servername` parameter for that.

```
$ echo '' | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.unival-logistics.com:443  -servername www.unival-logistics.com 2>/dev/null | grep -Ei 'subject|issuer|return'
subject=/C=US/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=www.unival-logistics.com
issuer=/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

If you leave that out, then you get the default certificate for that host. And here that is a self-signed certificate. (And I don't think it should be there either. Makes no sense to deliver a self-signed cert.)

```
 $ echo '' | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.unival-logistics.com:443  2>/dev/null | grep -Ei 'subject|issuer|return'
 subject=/O=americanfuturegate.com/CN=*.americanfuturegate.com/emailAddress=REDACTED1@example.com
 issuer=/O=americanfuturegate.com/CN=*.americanfuturegate.com/emailAddress=REDACTED1@example.com
     Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
```

## Check that installation

Side note: I urge you to disable SSL3. (SSL Labs report [here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=unival-logistics.com&hideResults=on).)

Comment: Thanks, eventually I figured it out, purchasing new certificate now...

Comment: Can you please remove my email from dmarc code...  Btw, I've resolved all problems...